# Send file POST C++

Tags: php, c++, http, winapi, post

I am trying to send a text file through POST to my upload.php form in php on my localhost webserver using C++.

Here is my php code for the request:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'upload/';

if (is_uploaded_file(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])?($_FILES['file'['tmp_name']):0)) 
{
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo "File ". $_FILES['file']['name'] ." uploaded successfully. ";

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
    {
        echo "File was moved! ";
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($_FILES);
    }
}
else 
{
    print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

The `upload` directory exists in the same directory as upload.php (contents above).

Here is the code which I am using to prepare the http request and send it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")
#define ERROR_OPEN_FILE       10
#define ERROR_MEMORY          11
#define ERROR_SIZE            12
#define ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN   13
#define ERROR_INTERNET_CONN   14
#define ERROR_INTERNET_REQ    15
#define ERROR_INTERNET_SEND   16

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 // Local variables
 static char *filename   = "test.txt";   //Filename to be loaded
 static char *filepath   = "C:\\wamp\\www\\post\\test.txt";   //Filename to be loaded
 static char *type       = "text/plain";
 static char boundary[]  = "--BOUNDARY---";            //Header boundary
 static char nameForm[]  = "file";     //Input form name
 static char iaddr[]     = "localhost";        //IP address
 static char url[]       = "/post/upload.php";         //URL

 char hdrs[512]={'-'};                  //Headers
 char * buffer;                   //Buffer containing file + headers
 char * content;                  //Buffer containing file
 FILE * pFile;                    //File pointer
 long lSize;                      //File size
 size_t result;                   

 // Open file
 pFile = fopen ( filepath , "rb" );
 if (pFile==NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_OPEN_FILE");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("OPEN_FILE\n");

 // obtain file size:
 fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
 lSize = ftell (pFile);
 rewind (pFile);

 // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
 content = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*(lSize+1));
 if (content == NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_MEMORY");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("MEMORY_ALLOCATED\t \"%d\" \n",&lSize);
 // copy the file into the buffer:
 result = fread (content,1,lSize,pFile);
 if (result != lSize) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_SIZE");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("SIZE_OK\n");

 content[lSize] = '\0';

 // terminate
 fclose (pFile);
 printf("FILE_CLOSE\n");
 //allocate memory to contain the whole file + HEADER
 buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize + 2048);

 //print header
 sprintf(hdrs,"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s",boundary);
 sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n",boundary,nameForm,filename);
 sprintf(buffer,"%sContent-Type: %s\r\n",buffer,type);
 sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n%s",buffer,content);
 sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n--%s--\r\n",buffer,boundary);

 printf("%s", buffer);

 //Open internet connection
 HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("WINDOWS",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
 if(hSession==NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_OPEN");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_OPEN_FILE;
 }
 printf("INTERNET_OPENED\n");

 HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, iaddr,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
 if(hConnect==NULL) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_CONN");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
 }
 printf("INTERNET_CONNECTED\n");

 HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, (const char*)"POST",_T(url),NULL, NULL, NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 1);
 if(hRequest==NULL) 
  {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_REQ");
     getchar();

 }
 printf("INTERNET_REQ_OPEN\n");

 BOOL sent= HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), buffer, strlen(buffer));

 if(!sent) 
 {
     printf("ERROR_INTERNET_SEND");
     getchar();
     return ERROR_INTERNET_CONN;
 }
 printf("INTERNET_SEND_OK\n");

 InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
 InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
 InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);

 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

When I execute the upload.exe (contents above). I get the following output:

```
OPEN_FILE
MEMORY_ALLOCATED    "1832340"
SIZE_OK
FILE_CLOSE
---BOUNDARY---
Content Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
test
---BOUNDARY---
INTERNET_OPENED
INTERNET_CONNECTED
INTERNET_REQ_OPEN
INTERNET_SEND_OK
```

Here is the PHP error log:

```
[12-Nov-2014 20:09:58 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:
[12-Nov-2014 20:09:58 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\post\upload.php:0
```

I'm a little confused as to what this means. Is this an error?

It appears everything goes through (note: the contents of test.txt are "test"). Though when I look in the `upload` directory. The test.txt file is not in there. The directory is empty. Can anyone help me understand what the problem is? Thank-you!

**BUMP** Does no one know how to do this or is it no possible? Because if it's not possible then just tell me so I can stop wasting my time searching.

Comment: Instead of just sending the file and stopping, read the response from the server, or log status to a file in PHP. That way, in PHP, you have information about what's happening so you can see what the server is doing.

Comment: @nickb Such as the one I just provided above upon your request?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think is_uploaded_file should get "" or NULL instead of 0? (In the If statement). I'm not sure that this is the problem. Perhaps go the old way and "echo debug" it? :)

Comment: I tried manually uploading the file with an index.html upload form which I created for test. It worked just fine. So I don't see this problem pertaining to my php code.

Comment: Turn on error reporting for PHP (a bunch of questions on SO show you how to do this with php.ini). Restart your web server and see what you get. I would also, in C++, read the response from the server, and print that out, instead of just sending the request (but I don't know what code to add to do that).

Comment: Error reporting is on, in php. And, in regards to reading the response from the server do you mean `InternetReadFile()`? Also, can I just use fiddler to view the response? If so, how?

Comment: Are you sure that the conditional operator is legal in an If statement?

Comment: Well the condition would traditionally `true` or `false` as it's a ternary operator. So in regards to the if statement it would simply be saying if success return true, if failure return false. On failure it would just die and result to the `else` statement. So there doesn't appear to be a problem there.

Comment: @sysenter I'm not sure, I don't know the API you're using in C++. But, you just send the request and do nothing else. My next step would be to read what response is coming back from the server. You should be able to get an HTTP status code, along with any content it may be serving up. And yes, if the PHP code works from a simple HTML form, its not the PHP, and we can assume the problem is elsewhrere.

Comment: Ok, didn't see that you tried HTML and it worked. So, have you compared the HTTP requests between the c++ client and the HTML form using Wireshark? It may give you an idea of where the problem might be with the request..

Comment: You could also debug this using Fidler \ Burp. Simply change your Internet Settings to use one of them as a proxy and the code you provided should try to connect through them.

Comment: Nothing unusual occurs when debugging with fiddler or wireshark. It says the request doesnt even touch the localhost end. Can someone let me know if there are any issues with my C++ code?

Comment: Ok, then open a fake server using NetCat to see the request:
    nc -lvvp 80

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why are you including `<iostream>` when you don't appear to be using it?

Comment: @TimSeguine `iostream` - Input/output stream ... without it I wouldn't be able to use printf() | getchar() in my code. I am using them to see what happens at each point in my code. To print to which point my code gets after execution.

Comment: @sysenter I know what `<iostream>` is. You aren't doing any stream IO. You are using only C library io routines, all of which are in stdio.h

Comment: Well I just like to use the C standard as opposed to the Cpp standard for debugging. That's all.

Comment: Ok, it was just a helpful hint that you are including the "wrong" header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your c++ client I found that the variable `content` which contains the content of the file doesn't end with a `NULL` so when you copy it with `sprintf` you are copying random bytes until a `NULL` appears.

Change the allocation to this:

```
 content = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*(lSize+1));
```

And after reading the contents of the file do this:

```
content[lSize] = '\0';
```

Also, I am quite sure that the `BOUNDARY` should start at a new line. So make this change too:

```
 sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n--%s--\r\n",buffer,boundary);
```

**Edit:**

By comparing a regular HTML form request, I can see that the content should start after two lines, so change this too:

```
sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n%s",buffer,content);
```

**Edit2:**

After testing with the PHP code, I found some more problems with the c++ code. 
(btw, there is a typo in the PHP code: missing `]` in the if statement)

The boundary isn't setup correctly.

The format of the mime should be like this:

```
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test2.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test
--BOUNDARY
```

The HTTP header should be like this:
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY

So the `sprintf`s should look like this:

```
sprintf(hdrs,"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s",boundary);
sprintf(buffer,"--%s\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n",boundary,nameForm,filename);
sprintf(buffer,"%sContent-Type: %s\r\n",buffer,type);
sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n%s",buffer,content);
sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n--%s\r\n",buffer,boundary);
```

After doing all of the fixes in this post, the code should work.

**To sum up:**

1. I would recommend using a VM setup to debug these kind of problems more easily because then you can use Wireshark\Fidler\Burp. (You can also try configuring proxy for localhost as well, never tried that myself. Also you can try using your external Internet IP and configure your router for port forwarding, but that's too complicated for this kind of task).
2. If that doesn't help, NetCat may help. Not as easy and friendly, but does the job.
3. Simply comparing a working example with your request output shows exactly what is missing. I used Beyond Compare for this. Always work with a comparing software since the human eye can be tricked easily.
4. The most obvious was to read the Mime specification and see exactly what is missing.

Comment: Did you happen to also test the client to server interface on a localhost? As even though reserving an extra byte at the EOF is generally smart in most strings. It doesn't really matter in this case since EOF is already assumed as a null-byte in itself. The outcome of your code here in my test gave the same results as before!

Comment: Well running your code gave me this output in the NetCat end: http://pastebin.com/kngJEjuL so the changes I suggested should fix these problems. I can't test the PHP right now.

Comment: Still nothing changes. I get the same output as you but it doesn't upload the file to the directory.

Comment: The output is wrong. The opening MIME boundary above the `Content-Disposition` header is missing the required leading `--` (yes, in addition to the leading `--` already in the declared boundary). That line needs to be `----BOUNDARY---` instead of `--BOUNDARY---`. Also, there is a missing line break after the text file content before the closing MIME boundary.

Comment: And there is a missing required line break between the `Content-Type: text/plain` header and the text file content.